# Pass a code of Python in a command line

Tags: python, command-line

Is it possible to somehow convert string which I pass via command line e.g

```
python myfile.py "s = list(range(1000))"
```

into module? And then...

```
#myfile.py
def printlist(s):
   print(s)
```

?

Something like a timeit module, but with my own code.

```
python -m timeit -s "s = list(range(1000))" "sorted(s)"
```

Comment: May I assume you do not actually want that particular function `printlist` but just some function that will print the result of the command you pass through the command line?

Comment: It is possible (with `exec()`), but very undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

Save the code

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

as `filename.py`, then run `python filename.py Hi there!` and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but the `sys` module has the attribute `argv` that is a list of all the arguments passed in the command line.

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for argument in sys.argv:
    print(argument)
```

This example will print every argument passed to the script, take in mind that the first element `sys.argv[0]` will always be the name of the script.

```
$ ./test.py hello there
./test.py
hello
there
```

Comment: Well, I need to make some operation on this list, I don't need it like a String. I'm not sure if it is possible.

Comment: it will always go into the program as a string. Its up to you to convert it to whatever else you need.

Comment: But I can't execute this part of code adding as an argument in command line?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to send short code snippets similar to what you can do via the `timeit` module or certain other `-m` module option functionality and these are:

You can use either the `-c` option of Python e.g.:
`python -c "<code here>"`

Or you could use piping such as:
`echo <code here> | python`

You can combine multiple statements using the `;` semicolon statement separator.  However if you use a `:` such as with `while` or `for` or `def` or `if` then you cannot use the `;` so there may be limited options.  Possibly some clever ways around this limitation but I have yet to see them.